# Test API REST SCALA

Tags: scala, testing

I am developing an application with Scala, Akka and Spray and I want to test the services of the API.

I do not understand how`spray-testkit` helps us in testing. I also tried `Specs2` and `ScalaTest` but neither of them are made to test APIs.

I just want a library that allow me to test API paths, adding headers, jsons to body and assert HTTP status and so son. What do you suggest me?

[EDIT]

I also tried Frisby.js and it is more simple. Maybe it is a better choice.

[EDIT -2]

I found Gatling. Does anyone know it??

Thanks!

Comment: Gatling is for performance testing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of @jmccure and also another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998553/how-can-i-simulate-a-post-request-with-a-json-body-in-spraytest) on SO and [this blog](http://sysgears.com/articles/scala-rest-api-integration-testing-with-spray-testkit/) I find the way to do it.

For example, this is how my first test looks like:

```
test("Create User") {
 Post("/users", user) ~> userRoutes ~> check {
  assert(
    status == OK
    && responseAs[User] == user
   ) 
  }
}
```

Where `user` is a case class that can be marshalled.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at some GET examples here:

https://github.com/blinkboxbooks/spray-search-service.scala/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/blinkbox/books/search/SearchApiTests.scala

For some POST examples, see:
https://github.com/blinkboxbooks/auth-service.scala/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/blinkbox/books/auth/server/api/UpdatePasswordSpecs.scala

Comment: That is a very nice example. However, only GET calls are made. I also need POST calls and I am not able to find how to do POST calls with a JSON body in ScalaTest.

Comment: Added a link to some POSTs

Answer (score 1):

Mentioned [gatling](https://gatling.io/), I need to advocate for it. It is IMHO successor of JMeter and it does miracles in terms of efficiency in performance testing (HTTP, AMQP, ...). You can take down any un-optimized web application with some small nettop easily.

Beware that [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) of gatling does heavily use fluent scripting and also builder pattern a lot. I.e. debugging your suite does require a bit of skill and knowledge of gatling internals.

For regression testing I would rather stick to scalatest, but if you mind, do all your tests in gatling. It can be really readable and it can doublecheck performance of your app if needed.