# API testing akka-http REST endpoint

Tags: scala, e2e-testing, akka-http, web-api-testing, spray-test

Here is my endpoint in akka-http:

```
private val route = Route.asyncHandler(
    pathPrefix("v0") {
       headerValueByType[JWTTokenObject](()) { jwtHeader => 
         mapRequest(authorize(jwtHeader.value)) {
           authenticateOrRejectWithChallenge(authenticate(transactionId, _)) { claims =>
               pathPrefix("v1"/Segment) { someValue => 
                  path("v3") {
                    post {
                        handleThisPostRequest(someValue)
                    }
                   }
                }
            }
         }
      }
)
```

This is one of the POST API which authenticates using JWT 'Bearer' token which is passed as a header value. I want to test this End To End. It is also calling DBs and third party services.

I am trying to add any API test framework so that I will be able to test this on any environments. Can you suggest any framework to achieve this type of integration tests where enviroment variables are involved in calling third party APIs.

Is it possible to test this using spray-testkit([Test API REST SCALA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28662637/test-api-rest-scala))?  An example will be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, the Akka Testkit(https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/testkit.html) has a wonderful suite for doing route an Actor testing. I would suggest using it.

Take a look to how to handle the Authorization token: https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/main/akka-http-tests/src/test/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/server/directives/SecurityDirectivesSpec.scala.

With respect to the environment variables: if you need that in your tests the code needs to call a remote service because is a integration or E2E test, make use of the capabilities of Scala config:
https://github.com/lightbend/config#optional-system-or-env-variable-overrides.

There are a lot of strategies about how to deal with testing in these kind of projects, but, in case ok Akka there are good resources to read about it.